# Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSecurityFilterChain'. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting error : Caused by: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSecurityFilterChain'. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once.`
I have Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE backed up by Spring Security - 5.3.4.RELEASE where in I have an SpringBootServletInitializer initializing my Application Context also have and class extending - AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer , I have SpringSecurityConfig.java class with below code.

```
@Configuration
@Import(SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages={     "com.services.security","com.services.security.config" })
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
PasswordGenerator pdgen;

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepositry;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
}
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
     
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

. I what to understand the Code flow around AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer since from the Source I could find that super.onStartup(servletContext); could make the springSecurityFilterChain configured , Is there any way that I could make in subclassing AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.especially using @Conditional constraints

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.spring.services</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-advsearch-services</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-advsearch-services Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<properties>
    <start-class>com.iii.advancesearch.services.app.ServletInitializer
    </start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <jackson.version.annotations>2.9.7</jackson.version.annotations>
    <spring-security.version>5.3.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <spring.version>5.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.3.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-solr -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- End of spring-boot-starter-data-solr -->
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency><!-- End of spring-boot-starter-data-solr -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency><!-- End of spring-boot-starter-data-solr -->
    <dependency><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure 
            ## dependency for spring-boot-starter -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core 
        spring-boot-starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jcl 
        dependency for spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.annotation/jakarta.annotation-api 
        dependency for spring-boot-starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-security-config 
            dependency for spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-security-web 
            dependency for spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop 
        dependency for spring-boot-starter-security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- Dependency for spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Oracle JDBC driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- Dependency for spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- Dependency for spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-json -->
    <dependency><!-- Dependency for spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring data JPA, default tomcat pool, exclude it -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api 
        dependency for spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.transaction/jakarta.transaction-api 
        dependency for spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core dependency 
        for spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/antlr/antlr dependency for hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/classmate dependency 
        for hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
        <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/javax.activation-api 
        dependency for hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api 
        dependency for hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api dependency 
        for hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy dependency 
        for hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime 
        dependency for hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations 
        dependency for hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist dependency 
        for hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.24.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jandex dependency for 
        hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging 
        dependency for hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec 
        dependency for hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects 
        dependency for spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver dependency 
        for spring-aspects -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop 
        dependency for spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.darkphoenixs</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.clerezza.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.json.simple</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>astra-advsearch-services</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.services.app.ServletInitializer
                        </mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>5_maven.restlet.org</id>
        <name>maven.restlet.org</name>
        <url>https://maven.restlet.org</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>webpublico-repository</id>
        <name>Webpublico Nexus Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.webpublico.com.br/repository/maven-public/
        </url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>1_central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>0_central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>1_maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>https://download.java.net/maven/2/
        </url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>2_repository.spring.release</id>
        <name>Spring
            GA Repository
        </name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>3_spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>4_maven.oracle.com</id>
        <name>oracle-maven-repo</name>
        <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>

    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
        <name>oracle-maven-repo</name>
        <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: this is too little information to answer, update your question with pom.xml file, project catalog structure and main file.

Comment: @EnableWebSecurity tag does the Spring Security MVC Auto Configuration .